# Unable to open CSV file

Tags: numbers, textedit, csv, launch-services

I have a reasonably sized CSV file (40 Megabytes). I know that some apps won't work with certain encodings, and that they will throw error if the encoding isn't ASCII. But its alarming that even **TextEdit.app** is unable to open this file.

First I tried **Numbers.app**. I made sure this isn't a Launch Services error, because I opened the file within the app. It wouldn't load. The progress bar always gets stuck half way. When I open this CSV file with **TextEdit.app**, it wouldn't load either. Not even Google Sheets. The file is just 40 Megabytes and has only ASCII characters. Running `file` command in **Terminal.app** returns the following message:

`file.csv: ASCII text, with very long lines`.

I am able to open the file using **Visual Studio Code** but not in **TextEdit.app**. How can I fix it? I cleaned the file for any `\r` characters.

**Update**: Running `wc -l file.csv` command returns `176831`. My system is a 2016 MacBookPro with 16 GB RAM.

Comment: How many lines does it have (run `wc -l FILE.csv` in Terminal to check)? What happens if you try to open it in Textedit?

Comment: Any reason you are looking to open it with a specific editor? Editors vary in their ability to handle a bulky file in memory. I generally see faster load times with **Sublime Text.app** over **TextEdit.app** for example.

Comment: Also, it would help if you can share your system configuration. Maybe the system doesn't have enough memory to load the CSV file gracefully.

Comment: i know, Im trying with text edit, and 40 megabytes seems reasonable

Comment: system has 16 gigs of ram

Comment: There appears no reason for the file to not load. Try looking at file contents by executing `less file.csv` and see if you can read the characters fine. Try opening the file again with **TextEdit.app** after doing a reboot.

Comment: I've run into situations where some apps won't load **BIG** files. I have had luck opening big files like that in BBEdit where textedit would just choke

Comment: wait guys, should i give a link to  google drive, would that help?

Comment: Run `cat file.csv` in terminal.

Comment: Can you give us a downloadable file? edited into question

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common for GUI programs to be unable to handle large text files. Although 40MB doesn't sound like large regarding todays standards, but that might bloat up to a lot more in memory depending on how the application is written. And GUI applications often aren't the most efficient ones.

You might want to split up the text file in multiple smaller ones using the terminal. First, check if you can open the file using `less filename.csv` in the Terminal, and if the characters read fine. If not, the file might be corrupted, and that might be the issue.

For the acutal splitting, try using something like this on the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10000 # Number of lines per file
i=1
j=0
filename="hugefile.csv"
extension=.csv
while [ $i -le $(wc -l $filename|awk '{print $1}') ]
do 
    newfilename="$(basename $filename $extension)$j$extension"
    echo $newfilename: $i
    sed -n $i,$((i+$N))p $filename > $newfilename
    j=$((j+1)); i=$((i+$N))
done
```

Copy and paste that into a plain text document (e.g. TextEdit in plain text mode or nano on the Terminal) and name it `split.sh` or something similiar. Customize the paramters `N` and `filename` as needed, e.g. enter the desired count of numbers per file in `N=...` and the filename of your sourcefile as `filename="..."`. This will generate the neccessary amount of files in your current directory to cover all the lines of the source files in smaller files of `N` lines each. The files will have a number appended, e.g. `hugefile0.txt` to `hugefile9.txt` or something like that.

Now you should be able to open each of these files in your desired application. It's often desirable to work with smaller portions of one large file than with the whole file at once. You could even open the resulting CSV files in Numbers one after another and copy the lines from each file into one large Numbers document. That way the importer probably won't hang on such a large file.

In case you get any errors regarding `sed` or `awk`, that's because Mac `sed` and `awk` are different than the regular `sed` or `awk`. In that case, you might need to install regular `sed` and `awk` from something like macports or homebrew.